# Gauss Date Calculation in Python

Tags: python

I’m trying to work out a formula to do Gauss date calculation.
My professor says its

```
x = year - (14 - month)/12
y = x + x/4 - x/100 + x/400
z = month + 12 * ((14 - month) /12) -2 
dow = (day + y + (31 * z)/12) % 7
```

With a Dow result of 0 being Sunday etc

But if I do any calculations using the formula, the result is always wrong.
I see I need to int it, so i surround the values by int(), though result is still incorrect.

Example today

```
Day = 2
Month = 5
Year = 2021


Dow = 2.16 so 2 so it says it’s a Tuesday?
```

Answer (score 2):

Omg so i worked it out, the issue is that in java it automatically makes each division an int and removes the decimal, but it doesn’t do that in python, so code has to be changed to.

```
x = year-int((14-month)/12)

y = int(x +(x / 4)) - int((x / 100)) + int((x / 400))

z = month + 12 * int((int((14 - month)) / 12)) - 2;

dow = (day + y + int((31*z)/12))%7
```